# How to convert Dataframe into key-Value pair in given format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, tuples

I have one Dataframe like this

```
     Number     String 

  0   12        Hi
  1   34        how
  2   35        are
```

Now i want to convert this into like given format

```
[(Number=12, String='hi'),(Number=34, String='How'),(Number=35, String='are')]
```

I tried this

```
tuples = [tup for tup in df.itertuples()]
```

which is returning me this result

```
[Pandas(Index=0, Number=12, String='hi'),
 Pandas(Index=1, Number=34, String='How'),
 Pandas(Index=2, Number=35, String='are')]
```

any suggestion?

Comment: `(Number=12, String='hi')` is not a valid Python format.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of tuples with a one-liner:

`[(k, v) for k,v in df.set_index('Number')['String'].to_dict().items()]`

Or a tuple of tuples:

`tuple((k, v) for k,v in df.set_index('Number')['String'].to_dict().items())`

```
> ((12, 'Hi'), (34, 'how'), (35, 'are'))
```

Comment: you have not seen my expected output . This is not what i want

Comment: You could iterate through the updated list of tuples and create a new list in the required format.

Comment: I thought about doing this with strings, but I have the feeling OP wants named tuples. I'm not really sure why